# Wordpress: Changing order of the posts with respect to an array

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress, I am trying to get posts by a specific order with respect to an array which includes post ids.

I tried to use pre_get_posts and $query->set functions to set post__in. But even it includes the posts in the array, it reorders them by post id.

But I want to keep the order as it is in the array.

```
function do_sortbyvotes($query)
{
if(get_query_var('sortbyvote') == 1) {
    $query->set('post__in',array(109, 152, 127)); 
}
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'do_sortbyvotes' );
```

This does not work the way i want to, it reorders..

How can I achieve this without Wordpress to reorder the posts by ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add an [`orderby`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) to your query.

```
$query->set('orderby','post__in');
```

This 'orderby' option is available only since WordPress 3.5, so it is a very recent addition.